# $f$ is an entire function satisfying the given condition . Show that the function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If an entire function $f(z)$ satisfies $$|f(z)|\le \frac{1+|z|}{1+\sqrt {|z|}}$$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$ then show that $f=c$ with $|c|\le 2(\sqrt 2-1)$.

First we consider a function $$g(z)=\frac{1+\sqrt{|z|}}{1+|z|}f(z).$$

As, $|z|\ge 0$ , so $g(z)$ is an entire function and $|g(z)|\le 1$. So, by Liovilles theorem $g$ is constant. Hence $f(z)$ is also constant as, $|z|$ is a real constant. But how we find the inequality about the constant ?

Comment: $g$, as written, is hardly entire.

Comment: I don't see why $g(z)$ is entire.  Care to explain?  Cheers!

Comment: I think considering $$\frac{1}{1+i\sqrt{z}}f(z)$$ (provided I haven't made a mistake in my mental arithmetic) in conjunction with Riemann's removable singularity theorem might help.

Comment: As, $|z|$ is a real number so I think the ratio is a constant..That's why I say that $g$ is entire

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 You don't know that it is a constant.. Just that the ratio is bounded by $1$ but there are plenty of nonholomophic functions which are bounded by $1$.

Comment: @@  Cameron Williams ))Ok..According to your construction , $|g(z)|\le \frac{1-i\sqrt z}{1+\sqrt z}$. Then how we can say that it is bounded  >?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$|f(z)| \leqslant \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{|z|}} +\frac{|z|}{1+\sqrt{|z|}} \leqslant \frac{1}{1+0} +\frac{|z|}{0+\sqrt{|z|}} \leqslant 1+\sqrt{|z|}$$

so we have $$|a_n | =\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{2\pi }\frac{1+\sqrt{r}}{r^{n+1}} \cdot{2\pi r} \to 0$$ as $r\to\infty$ for all $n>0.$ Hence $$f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$$ with $$a_n =0$$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ therefore $$f(z) =a_0 =\mbox{ constant }$$

Comment: Excellent idea......Thanks..

Comment: But how deduce the inequality about constant ?

Comment: Find a minimum of real valued function $h:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+ $ , $$h(\sigma ) =\frac{1 +\sigma }{1+\sqrt{\sigma }}$$

Comment: Ok...From your first line  it is clear that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $[1/2]$..that is $f$ is constant. You need not prove the Lioville's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless f=0, the function g is not differentiable in the complex plane and is,a fortiori,not entire. Hence we cannot apply Liouville's theorem to it.